# How to remove someone else's non-empty subdir from own dir in UNIX?

Tags: unix, filesystems

There's a really annoying situation.  I own a directory but someone else created a subdirectory in it that I'd like to delete but I cannot because it's not empty.  I thought, that owning the directory would give me the right to do that (I don't have root privileges).  What else can I do?

```
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x   4 myself   eng         4096  Jul 21 15:17 .
drwxrwxr-t 788 root     eng         69632 Jul 20 13:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x   4 someguy  eng         8192  Jul 21 15:13 stuff
$ ls -l stuff
-rw-r-----   4 someguy  eng         8192  Jul 21 15:13 somefile
drwxr-----   4 someguy  eng         8192  Jul 21 15:13 morestuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mv stuff ..
```

Comment: wont work. I got error while trying to move one directory to /tmp. I could move my own files to /tmp.

Comment: Read `man 2 rename`: "`EACCES` Write permission is denied for the directory containing `oldpath` or `newpath`, or, search permission  is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of `oldpath` or `newpath`, or `oldpath` is a directory and does not allow write  permission (needed to update the `..` entry)."  This clearly falls into the last situation.

Comment: Actually the OP does have write permission to oldpath (stuff), assuming he is in group eng.  (I assumed that since his directory was also owned by that group, and .. is not setgid.)

Comment: @Saurabh The directory has to be on the same filesystem, and you need write permission to the directory you are moving, as in the question.

Comment: Ah, right.  If you're doing a cross-filesystem `mv`, `rename` doesn't work and `mv` has to create new + remove old, which OP seems to lack permissions for.